# How JDBC connection to Oracle if NLS_CHARACTERSET=AZ8ISO8859P9E?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

**How JDBC connection to Oracle if NLS_CHARACTERSET=AZ8ISO8859P9E?**

I use `ojdbc6/java1.8/CentOS`. When I chance `NLS_CHARACTERSET` to `AL32UTF8` I can connect.

But I want connect when `NLS_CHARACTERSET` in Oracle DB equals `AZ8ISO8859P9E`.

This is Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

Comment: ? Can you more elaborate on your problem? You do not have to care about databases internal charset. And JDBC allays return string encoded in UTF16 so in case of JDBC you do not have to care even about session character set.  The conversion between the internal char set into the clients one is done on client's side.

Comment: what Oracle version you use and especially what exactly is the version of JDBC drivers you use?

Comment: oracle 11.2.0.4.0/ ojdbc6

Comment: execute: java -jar ojdbc6.jar and it will tell you more verbose driver version

Comment: As I wrote before. Final charset translation takes place on client. So client has to translate the databases internal charset into applications charset. For example OCI instant client supports only AL32UTF8 and ISO-8889-1. So you can not use it to connect to database using different charset. This is kind of trade-off between the size and flexibility. So even for instant client you have basic and multi-langual version

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AZ8ISO8859P9E;
```

if the above fails, use it:

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE AZ8ISO8859P9E;
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP;
```

Or

```
alter database character set UTF8;
```

Actually `AL32UTF8` is `UTF-8`

In Oracle you have also a character set called `UTF8`, this is a kind of misnomer and means Character set [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8).

As far as I know this is like `"UTF-8 as of Unicode version 3 from 1999"`.

You can use Unicode characters less than `65535` (Basic Multilingual Plane) `AL32UTF8` and `UTF8` are identical.

For checking charset which are capable with oracle. Check this
https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWUAD/wu_charsets.htm#GWUAD733

For **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**,

It is thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.
**So, Check your related code.**

Comment: Thank you for response, but don't want change AZ8ISO8859P9E.I want to connect to Oracle through Java when NLS_CHARACTERSET=AZ8ISO8859P9E

Comment: Then what problem you are facing?

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "scott",
                    "tiger");   i can't connection to Oracle. Because in Oracle DB NLS_CHARACTERSET=AZ8ISO8859P9E. But don't want change NLS_CHARACTERSET. I want other solution

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov What message are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Answer (score 0):

For starters, it is an epic failure not to create a database with `AL32UTF8`. Oracle highly discourages that.

In contrast to OCI, SQL*Plus, etc. JDBC/Java has no notion of `NLS_CHARACTERSET` because Java uses `String` which is always UTF-16. The driver will automatically convert your database character encoding to Java encoding. `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is only necessary for C/C++ apps for the driver to know how to convert database `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` to C's `char` type which is basically a byte type. So the string `İlham Əliyev` will be in `AL32UTF8` converted to C's `char` more than 12 bytes long, namely 14.

Comment: But when in Oracle DB my NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 I can connect from Java. When AZ8ISO8859P9E can't. What I must do?

Comment: @SaftarMurtuzov, provide log output which shows the erronous behavior.